# Thread is freezing the UI only in release mode in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler, android-looper

In my app, we are creating a thread for printing through the Bluetooth printer. it is working fine in debug mode but release mode it is giving ANR error. I am starting the thread from a service. I am using the following code:

```
@Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        while (!threadInitOK); // it is getting stuck here
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();

        if (null == mLooper)
            Log.v(TAG, "mLooper is null pointer");
        else
            Log.v(TAG, "mLooper is valid");
        workHandler = new WorkHandler();
        threadInitOK = true;
        Looper.loop();
    }
```

In lollipop version it is working fine it is only giving issue in Marshmellow version that too in release mode.

Comment: Why not just use HandlerThread instead of implementing an unstable mechanism like this?

Answer (score 0):

*I assume that your snippet is in a class that extend `Thread`*

`.start()` is certainly called from Main Thread in your code. So, it's not a good idea to make a blocking wait here (`while(...);`).

You have to use a non-blocking wait (callback, event, signal, ...) for getting information about your `Looper`. (eg: [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava))

You can use `HandlerThread` too (like @Kelevandos say in comment). You can see in [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java#L60) that it do exactly what you want.

If you give us more code and your goal, we can help you more.